# Line Comments in Standard ML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm learning ML, with the SML/NJ dialect. What I'm trying to figure out is if there is a line comment operator. I found the block comment operator, (* ... *), but I really miss line comments.

Suggestions? Or am I just stuck with block comments?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You're stuck with block comments.

On the other hand, block comments can be nested: `(* (* *) still comment here *)`

Comment: This makes me sad, but oh well. And the nested comments are cool, thanks.

Comment: For the record, that depends on your compiler/interactive environment. According to the spec, a comment may not contain the substring "*)", so you should avoid it even if some implementations are lenient.

Comment: @Nicholas Wilson: you are right, I got things mixed up with OCaml (http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html).

Comment: @NicholasWilson, just discovered this old answer. For the record, nested comments are explicitly allowed by the SML language spec ("Sec. 2.3: A comment is any character sequence within comment brackets `(*` `*)` in which comment brackets are properly nested"). All implementations support them correctly, and always have. Also, FWIW, both MLton and SML/NJ have recently implemented an old proposal for allowing line comments via `(*)`, although that's not shipping yet.

Comment: OK, I stand corrected -- but I think I did look it up five years ago, maybe I had an older spec from the library in my hand.

Answer (score 4):

[There is a RFC for line comments,](http://sml-family.org/successor-ml/OldSuccessorMLWiki/Line_comments.html) which proposes a hashmark followed by a whitespace.

Comment: I don't know who wrote up with that proposal, but it's incompatible with SML: `# a` already is valid syntax that is used in existing code. The proposal that has been implemented in some compilers is using `(*)` to start a line comment.

Comment: I don't know why I am being downvoted for mentioning an RFC.  I am just providing more information, not telling you how to vote.

Answer (score 1):

Single-line comments now ship in both MLton and SML/NJ, as long as you enable sML ("Successor ML") extensions (`sml -Cparser.succ-ml=true` for SML/NJ).

Here's a concrete example.  In the definition below, the value `1` is ignored, and the definition of `a` is taken from the next line (`2`) instead. (Below `=` denotes a continuation line, and please ignore the broken syntax highlighting.)

```ml
$ sml -Cparser.succ-ml=true
- val a = (*) 1
=   2;;
val a = 2 : int
```

See https://github.com/SMLFamily/Successor-ML/wiki/Summary-of-proposed-changes for more about sML.